# Android, Stretched Background with centered Image

Tags: android, xml, drawable, nine-patch

Hello fellow programmer,

I'm trying to create an xml for the background of my actionbar.

The background should stretch over the full length (9 patch), but the logo should just be centered.

I've tried it with a simple 9patch background and a custom view in the Actionbar in which the logo is centered. Problem is that if I add any buttons to the actionbar the custom view isn't using the full space anymore and the logo is offset to the left or right.
Now I'm trying to create an XML which stretches the background but centers the bitmap. Here is what I have so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/background" />
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/logo"  />
</layer-list>
```

The background is fine, but the logo also gets stretched over the full width / height, can you guys help me getting it centered?

Answer (score 0):

You need some specific needs, you can use your own Actionbar layout.

```
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(your View resource);
```